# How to consume APIs with RESTTemplate in Spring

Tags: java, spring, rest

Apologizes in advance for such a stupid question but I'm attempting to create consume a Rest API  from a site RESTcountries.eu that generates the following data:

```
[{"name":"Estonia","topLevelDomain":[".ee"],"alpha2Code":"EE","alpha3Code":"EST","callingCodes":["372"],"capital":"Tallinn","altSpellings":["EE","Eesti","Republic of Estonia","Eesti Vabariik"],"region":"Europe","subregion":"Northern Europe","population":1315944,"latlng":[59.0,26.0],"demonym":"Estonian","area":45227.0,"gini":36.0,"timezones":["UTC+02:00"],"borders":["LVA","RUS"],"nativeName":"Eesti","numericCode":"233","currencies":[{"code":"EUR","name":"Euro","symbol":"€"}],"languages":[{"iso639_1":"et","iso639_2":"est","name":"Estonian","nativeName":"eesti"}],"translations":{"de":"Estland","es":"Estonia","fr":"Estonie","ja":"エストニア","it":"Estonia","br":"Estônia","pt":"Estónia"},"flag":"https://restcountries.eu/data/est.svg","regionalBlocs":[{"acronym":"EU","name":"European Union","otherAcronyms":[],"otherNames":[]}]}]
```

I seem to get an error everytime I attempt to run the program. Thanks in advance for any help.

I have the classes:

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class BaseCountries {

    private String name;
    private List<String> topLevelDomain;
    private String alpha2Code;
    private String alpha3Code;
    private List<String> callingCodes;   
    private String capital;
    private List<String> altSpellings;
    private String relevance;
    private String region;
    private String subregion;
    private Integer population;
    private List<Double> latlng;
    private String demonym;
    private Double area;
    private Double gini;
    private List<String> timezones;
    private List<String> borders;
    private String nativeName;
    private String numericCode;

    //Getters and Setters

    }
}
```

and this as my Main:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan("com.ronone.service")
public class WorldStatsApplication {

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(WorldStatsApplication.class);

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String uri = "https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/capital/{capital}";
        SpringApplication.run(WorldStatsApplication.class, args);

        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
        BaseCountries country = restTemplate.getForObject(uri, BaseCountries.class, "London");

        System.out.println("Country Name: " + country.getCapital());


    }

}
```

Print Trace:

```
2017-06-17 22:21:58.336  INFO 1062 --- [  restartedMain] c.r.WorldStats.WorldStatsApplication     : Starting WorldStatsApplication on Ronalds-MacBook-Pro.local with PID 1062 (started by ronaldpitt in /Users/ronaldpitt/Desktop/Java Apps/WorldStats)
2017-06-17 22:21:58.338  INFO 1062 --- [  restartedMain] c.r.WorldStats.WorldStatsApplication     : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2017-06-17 22:21:58.413  INFO 1062 --- [  restartedMain] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@4984bfe5: startup date [Sat Jun 17 22:21:58 EDT 2017]; root of context hierarchy
2017-06-17 22:21:59.432  INFO 1062 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Overriding bean definition for bean 'httpRequestHandlerAdapter' with a different definition: replacing [Root bean: class [null]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=3; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration; factoryMethodName=httpRequestHandlerAdapter; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=(inferred); defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration.class]] with [Root bean: class [null]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=3; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.config.RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration; factoryMethodName=httpRequestHandlerAdapter; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=(inferred); defined in class path resource [org/springframework/data/rest/webmvc/config/RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration.class]]
2017-06-17 22:22:00.833  INFO 1062 --- [  restartedMain] s.b.c.e.t.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2017-06-17 22:22:00.855  INFO 1062 --- [  restartedMain] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2017-06-17 22:22:00.856  INFO 1062 --- [  restartedMain] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.5.15
2017-06-17 22:22:00.982  INFO 1062 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2017-06-17 22:22:00.983  INFO 1062 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 2576 ms
2017-06-17 22:22:01.207  INFO 1062 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.ServletRegistrationBean  : Mapping servlet: 'dispatcherServlet' to [/]
2017-06-17 22:22:01.213  INFO 1062 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'characterEncodingFilter' to: [/*]
2017-06-17 22:22:01.214  INFO 1062 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'hiddenHttpMethodFilter' to: [/*]
2017-06-17 22:22:01.214  INFO 1062 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'httpPutFormContentFilter' to: [/*]
2017-06-17 22:22:01.214  INFO 1062 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'requestContextFilter' to: [/*]
2017-06-17 22:22:02.125  INFO 1062 --- [  restartedMain] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter : Looking for @ControllerAdvice: org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@4984bfe5: startup date [Sat Jun 17 22:21:58 EDT 2017]; root of context hierarchy
2017-06-17 22:22:02.243  INFO 1062 --- [  restartedMain] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/error]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.Object>> org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.BasicErrorController.error(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest)
2017-06-17 22:22:02.245  INFO 1062 --- [  restartedMain] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/error],produces=[text/html]}" onto public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.BasicErrorController.errorHtml(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse)
2017-06-17 22:22:02.306  INFO 1062 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/webjars/**] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2017-06-17 22:22:02.306  INFO 1062 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/**] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2017-06-17 22:22:02.329  INFO 1062 --- [  restartedMain] .m.m.a.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver : Detected @ExceptionHandler methods in repositoryRestExceptionHandler
2017-06-17 22:22:02.436  INFO 1062 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/**/favicon.ico] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2017-06-17 22:22:02.587  INFO 1062 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.d.r.w.RepositoryRestHandlerAdapter   : Looking for @ControllerAdvice: org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@4984bfe5: startup date [Sat Jun 17 22:21:58 EDT 2017]; root of context hierarchy
2017-06-17 22:22:02.603  INFO 1062 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.d.r.w.RepositoryRestHandlerMapping   : Mapped "{[/ || ],methods=[OPTIONS],produces=[application/hal+json || application/json]}" onto public org.springframework.http.HttpEntity<?> org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositoryController.optionsForRepositories()
2017-06-17 22:22:02.604  INFO 1062 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.d.r.w.RepositoryRestHandlerMapping   : Mapped "{[/ || ],methods=[GET],produces=[application/hal+json || application/json]}" onto public org.springframework.http.HttpEntity<org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositoryLinksResource> org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositoryController.listRepositories()
2017-06-17 22:22:02.604  INFO 1062 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.d.r.w.RepositoryRestHandlerMapping   : Mapped "{[/ || ],methods=[HEAD],produces=[application/hal+json || application/json]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<?> org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositoryController.headForRepositories()
2017-06-17 22:22:02.608  INFO 1062 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.d.r.w.RepositoryRestHandlerMapping   : Mapped "{[/{repository}/{id}/{property}],methods=[GET],produces=[application/hal+json || application/json]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<org.springframework.hateoas.ResourceSupport> org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositoryPropertyReferenceController.followPropertyReference(org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RootResourceInformation,java.io.Serializable,java.lang.String,org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.PersistentEntityResourceAssembler) throws java.lang.Exception
2017-06-17 22:22:02.608  INFO 1062 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.d.r.w.RepositoryRestHandlerMapping   : Mapped "{[/{repository}/{id}/{property}/{propertyId}],methods=[GET],produces=[application/hal+json || application/json]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<org.springframework.hateoas.ResourceSupport> org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositoryPropertyReferenceController.followPropertyReference(org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RootResourceInformation,java.io.Serializable,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.PersistentEntityResourceAssembler) throws java.lang.Exception
2017-06-17 22:22:02.609  INFO 1062 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.d.r.w.RepositoryRestHandlerMapping   : Mapped "{[/{repository}/{id}/{property}],methods=[DELETE],produces=[application/hal+json || application/json]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<? extends org.springframework.hateoas.ResourceSupport> org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositoryPropertyReferenceController.deletePropertyReference(org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RootResourceInformation,java.io.Serializable,java.lang.String) throws java.lang.Exception
2017-06-17 22:22:02.609  INFO 1062 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.d.r.w.RepositoryRestHandlerMapping   : Mapped "{[/{repository}/{id}/{property}],methods=[GET],produces=[application/x-spring-data-compact+json || text/uri-list]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<org.springframework.hateoas.ResourceSupport> org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositoryPropertyReferenceController.followPropertyReferenceCompact(org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RootResourceInformation,java.io.Serializable,java.lang.String,org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.PersistentEntityResourceAssembler) throws java.lang.Exception
2017-06-17 22:22:02.610  INFO 1062 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.d.r.w.RepositoryRestHandlerMapping   : Mapped "{[/{repository}/{id}/{property}],methods=[PATCH || PUT || POST],consumes=[application/json || application/x-spring-data-compact+json || text/uri-list],produces=[application/hal+json || application/json]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<? extends org.springframework.hateoas.ResourceSupport> org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositoryPropertyReferenceController.createPropertyReference(org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RootResourceInformation,org.springframework.http.HttpMethod,org.springframework.hateoas.Resources<java.lang.Object>,java.io.Serializable,java.lang.String) throws java.lang.Exception
2017-06-17 22:22:02.610  INFO 1062 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.d.r.w.RepositoryRestHandlerMapping   : Mapped "{[/{repository}/{id}/{property}/{propertyId}],methods=[DELETE],produces=[application/hal+json || application/json]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<org.springframework.hateoas.ResourceSupport> org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositoryPropertyReferenceController.deletePropertyReferenceId(org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RootResourceInformation,java.io.Serializable,java.lang.String,java.lang.String) throws java.lang.Exception
2017-06-17 22:22:02.616  INFO 1062 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.d.r.w.RepositoryRestHandlerMapping   : Mapped "{[/{repository}/search],methods=[OPTIONS],produces=[application/hal+json || application/json]}" onto public org.springframework.http.HttpEntity<?> org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositorySearchController.optionsForSearches(org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RootResourceInformation)
2017-06-17 22:22:02.617  INFO 1062 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.d.r.w.RepositoryRestHandlerMapping   : Mapped "{[/{repository}/search],methods=[HEAD],produces=[application/hal+json || application/json]}" onto public org.springframework.http.HttpEntity<?> org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositorySearchController.headForSearches(org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RootResourceInformation)
2017-06-17 22:22:02.617  INFO 1062 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.d.r.w.RepositoryRestHandlerMapping   : Mapped "{[/{repository}/search],methods=[GET],produces=[application/hal+json || application/json]}" onto public org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositorySearchesResource org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositorySearchController.listSearches(org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RootResourceInformation)
2017-06-17 22:22:02.618  INFO 1062 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.d.r.w.RepositoryRestHandlerMapping   : Mapped "{[/{repository}/search/{search}],methods=[GET],produces=[application/hal+json || application/json]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<?> org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositorySearchController.executeSearch(org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RootResourceInformation,org.springframework.util.MultiValueMap<java.lang.String, java.lang.Object>,java.lang.String,org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.support.DefaultedPageable,org.springframework.data.domain.Sort,org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.PersistentEntityResourceAssembler,org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders)
2017-06-17 22:22:02.619  INFO 1062 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.d.r.w.RepositoryRestHandlerMapping   : Mapped "{[/{repository}/search/{search}],methods=[GET],produces=[application/x-spring-data-compact+json]}" onto public org.springframework.hateoas.ResourceSupport org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositorySearchController.executeSearchCompact(org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RootResourceInformation,org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders,org.springframework.util.MultiValueMap<java.lang.String, java.lang.Object>,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.support.DefaultedPageable,org.springframework.data.domain.Sort,org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.PersistentEntityResourceAssembler)
2017-06-17 22:22:02.620  INFO 1062 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.d.r.w.RepositoryRestHandlerMapping   : Mapped "{[/{repository}/search/{search}],methods=[OPTIONS],produces=[application/hal+json || application/json]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<java.lang.Object> org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositorySearchController.optionsForSearch(org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RootResourceInformation,java.lang.String)
2017-06-17 22:22:02.620  INFO 1062 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.d.r.w.RepositoryRestHandlerMapping   : Mapped "{[/{repository}/search/{search}],methods=[HEAD],produces=[application/hal+json || application/json]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<java.lang.Object> org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositorySearchController.headForSearch(org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RootResourceInformation,java.lang.String)
2017-06-17 22:22:02.623  INFO 1062 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.d.r.w.RepositoryRestHandlerMapping   : Mapped "{[/{repository}],methods=[OPTIONS],produces=[application/hal+json || application/json]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<?> org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositoryEntityController.optionsForCollectionResource(org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RootResourceInformation)
2017-06-17 22:22:02.624  INFO 1062 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.d.r.w.RepositoryRestHandlerMapping   : Mapped "{[/{repository}],methods=[HEAD],produces=[application/hal+json || application/json]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<?> org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositoryEntityController.headCollectionResource(org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RootResourceInformation,org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.support.DefaultedPageable) throws org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException
2017-06-17 22:22:02.625  INFO 1062 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.d.r.w.RepositoryRestHandlerMapping   : Mapped "{[/{repository}],methods=[GET],produces=[application/hal+json || application/json]}" onto public org.springframework.hateoas.Resources<?> org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositoryEntityController.getCollectionResource(org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RootResourceInformation,org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.support.DefaultedPageable,org.springframework.data.domain.Sort,org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.PersistentEntityResourceAssembler) throws org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.ResourceNotFoundException,org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException
2017-06-17 22:22:02.625  INFO 1062 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.d.r.w.RepositoryRestHandlerMapping   : Mapped "{[/{repository}],methods=[GET],produces=[application/x-spring-data-compact+json || text/uri-list]}" onto public org.springframework.hateoas.Resources<?> org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositoryEntityController.getCollectionResourceCompact(org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RootResourceInformation,org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.support.DefaultedPageable,org.springframework.data.domain.Sort,org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.PersistentEntityResourceAssembler) throws org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.ResourceNotFoundException,org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException
2017-06-17 22:22:02.626  INFO 1062 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.d.r.w.RepositoryRestHandlerMapping   : Mapped "{[/{repository}],methods=[POST],produces=[application/hal+json || application/json]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<org.springframework.hateoas.ResourceSupport> org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositoryEntityController.postCollectionResource(org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RootResourceInformation,org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.PersistentEntityResource,org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.PersistentEntityResourceAssembler,java.lang.String) throws org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException
2017-06-17 22:22:02.626  INFO 1062 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.d.r.w.RepositoryRestHandlerMapping   : Mapped "{[/{repository}/{id}],methods=[OPTIONS],produces=[application/hal+json || application/json]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<?> org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositoryEntityController.optionsForItemResource(org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RootResourceInformation)
2017-06-17 22:22:02.626  INFO 1062 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.d.r.w.RepositoryRestHandlerMapping   : Mapped "{[/{repository}/{id}],methods=[HEAD],produces=[application/hal+json || application/json]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<?> org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositoryEntityController.headForItemResource(org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RootResourceInformation,java.io.Serializable,org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.PersistentEntityResourceAssembler) throws org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException
2017-06-17 22:22:02.627  INFO 1062 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.d.r.w.RepositoryRestHandlerMapping   : Mapped "{[/{repository}/{id}],methods=[GET],produces=[application/hal+json || application/json]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<org.springframework.hateoas.Resource<?>> org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositoryEntityController.getItemResource(org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RootResourceInformation,java.io.Serializable,org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.PersistentEntityResourceAssembler,org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders) throws org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException
2017-06-17 22:22:02.628  INFO 1062 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.d.r.w.RepositoryRestHandlerMapping   : Mapped "{[/{repository}/{id}],methods=[PUT],produces=[application/hal+json || application/json]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<? extends org.springframework.hateoas.ResourceSupport> org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositoryEntityController.putItemResource(org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RootResourceInformation,org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.PersistentEntityResource,java.io.Serializable,org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.PersistentEntityResourceAssembler,org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.support.ETag,java.lang.String) throws org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException
2017-06-17 22:22:02.628  INFO 1062 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.d.r.w.RepositoryRestHandlerMapping   : Mapped "{[/{repository}/{id}],methods=[PATCH],produces=[application/hal+json || application/json]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<org.springframework.hateoas.ResourceSupport> org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositoryEntityController.patchItemResource(org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RootResourceInformation,org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.PersistentEntityResource,java.io.Serializable,org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.PersistentEntityResourceAssembler,org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.support.ETag,java.lang.String) throws org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException,org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.ResourceNotFoundException
2017-06-17 22:22:02.629  INFO 1062 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.d.r.w.RepositoryRestHandlerMapping   : Mapped "{[/{repository}/{id}],methods=[DELETE],produces=[application/hal+json || application/json]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<?> org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositoryEntityController.deleteItemResource(org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RootResourceInformation,java.io.Serializable,org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.support.ETag) throws org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.ResourceNotFoundException,org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException
2017-06-17 22:22:02.633  INFO 1062 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.d.r.w.BasePathAwareHandlerMapping    : Mapped "{[/profile],methods=[GET]}" onto org.springframework.http.HttpEntity<org.springframework.hateoas.ResourceSupport> org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.ProfileController.listAllFormsOfMetadata()
2017-06-17 22:22:02.634  INFO 1062 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.d.r.w.BasePathAwareHandlerMapping    : Mapped "{[/profile],methods=[OPTIONS]}" onto public org.springframework.http.HttpEntity<?> org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.ProfileController.profileOptions()
2017-06-17 22:22:02.635  INFO 1062 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.d.r.w.BasePathAwareHandlerMapping    : Mapped "{[/profile/{repository}],methods=[OPTIONS],produces=[application/alps+json]}" onto org.springframework.http.HttpEntity<?> org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.alps.AlpsController.alpsOptions()
2017-06-17 22:22:02.635  INFO 1062 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.d.r.w.BasePathAwareHandlerMapping    : Mapped "{[/profile/{repository}],methods=[GET],produces=[application/alps+json || */*]}" onto org.springframework.http.HttpEntity<org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RootResourceInformation> org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.alps.AlpsController.descriptor(org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RootResourceInformation)
2017-06-17 22:22:02.636  INFO 1062 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.d.r.w.BasePathAwareHandlerMapping    : Mapped "{[/profile/{repository}],methods=[GET],produces=[application/schema+json]}" onto public org.springframework.http.HttpEntity<org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.json.JsonSchema> org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositorySchemaController.schema(org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RootResourceInformation)
2017-06-17 22:22:02.779  INFO 1062 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.d.a.OptionalLiveReloadServer       : LiveReload server is running on port 35729
2017-06-17 22:22:02.895  INFO 1062 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Registering beans for JMX exposure on startup
2017-06-17 22:22:02.992  INFO 1062 --- [  restartedMain] s.b.c.e.t.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http)
2017-06-17 22:22:03.002  INFO 1062 --- [  restartedMain] c.r.WorldStats.WorldStatsApplication     : Started WorldStatsApplication in 15.161 seconds (JVM running for 16.137)
Exception in thread "restartedMain" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49)
Caused by: org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: JSON parse error: Can not deserialize instance of com.ronone.WorldStats.models.BaseCountries out of START_ARRAY token; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not deserialize instance of com.ronone.WorldStats.models.BaseCountries out of START_ARRAY token
 at [Source: java.io.PushbackInputStream@775df1ae; line: 1, column: 1]
    at org.springframework.http.converter.json.AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.readJavaType(AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java:244)
    at org.springframework.http.converter.json.AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.read(AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java:229)
    at org.springframework.web.client.HttpMessageConverterExtractor.extractData(HttpMessageConverterExtractor.java:96)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:655)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:613)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.getForObject(RestTemplate.java:287)
    at com.ronone.WorldStats.WorldStatsApplication.main(WorldStatsApplication.java:25)
    ... 5 more
Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not deserialize instance of com.ronone.WorldStats.models.BaseCountries out of START_ARRAY token
 at [Source: java.io.PushbackInputStream@775df1ae; line: 1, column: 1]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException.from(JsonMappingException.java:270)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.reportMappingException(DeserializationContext.java:1234)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.handleUnexpectedToken(DeserializationContext.java:1122)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.handleUnexpectedToken(DeserializationContext.java:1075)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializerBase.deserializeFromArray(BeanDeserializerBase.java:1371)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer._deserializeOther(BeanDeserializer.java:174)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:150)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:3798)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:2922)
    at org.springframework.http.converter.json.AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.readJavaType(AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java:241)
    ... 11 more
2017-06-17 22:23:23.932  INFO 1062 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2017-06-17 22:23:23.933  INFO 1062 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet': initialization started
2017-06-17 22:23:23.990  INFO 1062 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet': initialization completed in 56 ms
```

Comment: The type of `BaseCountries` is an array. So, you should map your `RestTemplate` that to a list or array of `BaseCountries` class rather pointing to class alone.

Comment: You can try this `BaseCountries[] countries = restTemplate.getForObject(uri, BaseCountries[].class, "London");`

Comment: That worked, thank you @harshavmb

Comment: Glad to know it helped you!

Answer (score 2):

Your json to pojo mapping is incorrect. It should be mapped to an array of `BaseCountries` rather being mapped to class alone.

You can try this `BaseCountries[] countries = restTemplate.getForObject(uri, BaseCountries[].class, "London");`

Hope this helps!